# Alternative for using eval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my Javascript I have a kind of factory.
Depending the string is passed I create a new instance of this string as an object.
For example

```
    function getEmployee (employeeType, department){
        var fn = eval(employeeType);
        return new fn(department);
    }
```

I don't wanna use eval over here.
I could use a switch statement on the employeeType, but I don't want any dependencies of having to know the employeeType.

Is there another way how I could do it ?

Comment: Can you create a global registry of employee types, e.g. `var employeeTypes = { "manager": Manager, "intern": Intern }`? or would you count this as a dependency?

Comment: `fn = window[employeeType]` is an alternative if you don't know the types in advance, but @p.s.w.g's solution is safer. In any case, no need for `evil()`.

Comment: Could you not just have employeeType being a object with different prototypes for the factory?

Answer (score 5):

To expand on my original comment, whenever I've encountered a problem like this, the general solution is to create some sort of global registry of valid names:

```
function Manager() { /* manager employee type */ }
function Intern() { /* intern employee type */ }

var registeredTypes = {
    "manager": Manager,
    "intern": Intern
};
```

Then write your function as:

```
function getEmployee (employeeType, department) {
    if (!(employeeType in registeredTypes)) 
        throw "Invalid employee type: " + employeeType;
    var fn = registeredTypes[employeeType];
    return new fn(department);
}
```

However, if you're really concerned about dependencies, you can even separate this out a bit further by providing a global method to add new employee types to the registry:

```
function registerEmployeeType(employeeType, fn) {
    if (employeeType in registeredTypes) 
        throw "Employee type already registered: " + employeeType;
    if (typeof(fn) != "function")
        throw "May only register employee types as functions: " + employeeType;
    registeredTypes[employeeType] = fn;
}
```

Now your core functions, `getEmployee` and `registerEmployeeType`, can be declared by themselves without any information about the employee types being registered.  They can even be registered from different script files, provided they are run *after* the `registerEmployeeType` is defined. For example:

```
// core.js
var registeredTypes = { };
function getEmployee (employeeType, department) ...
function registerEmployeeType (employeeType, fn) ...

// manager.js
registerEmployeeType("manager", function() { /* manager employee type */ });

// intern.js
registerEmployeeType("intern", function() { /* intern employee type */ });

// index.html
<script src="core.js"></script>
<script src="manager.js"></script>
<script src="intern.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi p.s.w.g 
Thank you for your input. This would work, but the caller of the factory doesn't have the employeeType as object, only as a string.
This is because the caller is from another project and has only an array of strings.
The factory calls another application, where the real classes lives.

Comment: @RalfD'hooge That's exactly what my solution provides. In fact, the only difference between your version and mine is that I've included a `if` check to make sure the caller didn't do something strange like call `getEmployee("toString")`.

Comment: I included it in my answer that it was thanks to you I have the solution. And I will put also in my application the extra checks as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing a function for `employeeType` instead of a string (or more classically - an object with a fixed method), then call the function instead of `eval` it.

Comment: There are times when this isn't an option. E.g. if you're parsing a Json result in the form `{ "employees":[ { "name":"Joe", "type":"manager" }, { "name":"Sally", "type":"intern" } ] }`. At some point you have to map the string `"manager"` to the function `Manager`. But granted, OP hasn't told us enough to know if this is one of those times.

Comment: This is the case p.s.w.g 
And the actually object functions lives in another project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to p.s.w.g I have found the answer.
I register the types before my factory.
I still pass the type as a string to my factory, but look it up in the registered types.

So thx all for your comments.

```
function getEmployee (employeeType, department){
    var fn = registeredTypes[employeeType];
    return new fn(department);
}
```